# How to move texture via rig

Tags: modeling, texturing, rigging, armature

I'm trying to make a character model where I can move the pupils. Is there a way I can make the eyes so that I can move the pupil texture around the eye using a rig?

Comment: To my knowledge textures can't be rigged.

Comment: I’ve seen other people do it.

Comment: You can add drivers to the uv coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You can parent an object, e.g. an Empty, to a bone in a rig and then use that object's location as texture coordinates in the Eye object's material.
This way the Empty will follow the Rig, and the Texture will follow the Empty.

Add an empty to your scene and place it where you want the pupil to be on the eye.
Select your armature and go into Pose mode.
Click on your Empty
Shift-click on the bone
CTRL-P -> Bone

Now the empty will follow the bone.

In the shader editor for your eye material:
Shift-A -> Texture Coordinates.
Select your empty from the Object field at the bottom of this node.
Use the Object output of the Texture Coordinates node as coordinates for your texture. Remember that Image textures usually use only the X and Y components of their coordinates vector, so you may have to rotate your empty so that Y is up/down, or you could swizzle the Y and Z components of the vector using SeparateXYZ and CombineXYZ nodes by simply plugging X to X, and Z to Y.

Answer (score 0):

This result can be obtained by keyframing the texture's offset in the texture's Mapping panel. **Rigging** is done with **bones** and applies to **meshes** that are **3D** whereas textures are images.